# Static viewport width

Tags: html, css, size, screen, viewport

I want my website to have a static viewport width of 350px. Always. Those 350px should span the entire device width. How do I do this? Is the `<meta name="viewport">` enough? I tried setting the `width=350`, but that didn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

for a static viewport you must set the content on the meta tag.
try like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=350">
```

**Note :** You can't notice the change in desktop.